# Mod-security and WordPress WAF

Tags: wordpress, waf, mod-security

On my WordPress websites (on LEMP stack with Nginx) I normally install a WAF plugin such as Ninja Firewall or Wordfence.

I was wondering if a better practice would be to replace them with a host-based WAF like mod-security (I guess that running both wouldn't be recommended...).

Comment: Each of those tools are meant for different threats

Comment: Why wouldn't running both be recommended?

Comment: @schroeder
Can you explain further for which threats are they meant?

Comment: @multithr3at3d: I guess there has to be significant overlap between both, and this may hurt performance for no clear benefit. I am not familiar with Wordfence but I would make an assumption that it is fined-tuned for Wordpress and may be better suited than a generic WAF If you just running Wordpress. Just a thought.